# Subset selection with LASSO involving categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, lasso-regression

I ran a LASSO algorithm on a dataset that has multiple categorical variables. When I used model.matrix() function on the independent variables, it automatically created dummy values for each factor level.

For example, I have a variable "worker_type" that has three values: FTE, contr, other. Here, reference is modality "FTE".

Some other categorical variables have more or fewer factor levels.

When I output the coefficients results from LASSO, I noticed that worker_typecontr and worker_typeother both have coefficients zero. How should I interpret the results? What's the coefficient for FTE in this case? Should I just take this variable out of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this question is suited more for **Cross Validated**.

Ridge Regression and the Lasso are both "shrinkage" methods, typically used to deal with high dimensional predictor space.

The fact that your Lasso regression reduces some of the beta coefficients to zero indicates that the Lasso is doing exactly what it is designed for! By its mathematical definition, the Lasso assumes that a number of the coefficients are truly equal to zero. The interpretation of coefficients that go to zero is that these predictors do not explain any of the variance in the response compared to the non-zero predictors.

Why does the Lasso shrink some coefficients to zero? We need to investigate how the coefficients are chosen. The Lasso is essentially a multiple linear regression problem that is solved by minimizing the Residual Sum of Squares, plus a special L1 penalty term that shrinks coefficients to 0. This is the term that is minimized:

[image]

where *p* is the number of predictors, and *lambda* is a a non-negative tuning parameter. When *lambda = 0*, the penalty term drops out, and you have a multiple linear regression. As *lambda* becomes larger, your model fit will have less bias, but higher variance (ie - it will be subject to overfitting).

A cross-validation approach should be taken towards selecting the appropriate tuning parameter *lambda*. Take a grid of *lambda* values, and compute the cross-validation error for each value of *lambda* and select the tuning parameter value for which the cross-validation error is the lowest.

The Lasso is useful in some situations and helps in generating simple models, but special consideration should be paid to the nature of the data itself, and whether or not another method such as Ridge Regression, or OLS Regression is more appropriate given how many predictors should be truly related to the response.

Note: See equation 6.7 on page 221 in "An Introduction to Statistical Learning", which you can download for free [here](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf).

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks a lot for your response. I might have misinterpreted my question. I am actually familiar with the mathematical logic behind LASSO. What I am struggling with is that when the dummy variables for a categorical variable are created, i.e. {worker_typecontr:[0,1,0], worker_typeother: [0,0,1]} indicting the first 3 rows in the worker_type field is FTE, contr, other, respectively. As LASSO algorithm outputs, both worker_typecontr and worker_typeother have coefficients zero. Does that mean I need to take out this worker_type feature entirely?

Comment: I believe that means the Lasso has shrunken those coefficients to zero.